# Low profile graphic card with two analog outputs

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, low-profile

I need a low profile graphic card that supports two analog outputs (the second one usually through a DVI-DSUB adapter). In the past I used [ASUS EAH3450/DI/256M](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=fNpjfXkSvd4uu8No), but I can't find it right now. Another option could be [PowerColor HD3450 256MB HDMI](http://www.powercolor.com/global/products_features.asp?id=70), but it also is hard to find in stores.

Are there any newer models that accepts two analog outputs? For the record [ASUS EAH3450 SILENT/DI/512MD2](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=s0jHs2kvfGcKNU2R), even if it has the same chip, doesn't support two analog outputs.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the dedicated GPUs in Dell computers often have a bizarre (possibly proprietary) connector on the card, and then you can attach an adapter to either split it into two DVIs or two VGAs. If you can find one of these somewhere (perhaps in a used Dell computer), or if any other manufacturers sell them, that might work for you.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll try to find one, but my chances are slim in my area.